# SailsJS Log Request Params

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, request, sails.js

so my problem is that I want to log any request to my sails app. Basically I've got it working with the one problem that I can't log the params of the request.

```
myRequestLogger: function(req, res, next) {
            if (sails.config.environment === 'development') {
                console.log('=========================================================');

                console.log("Request :: ", req.method, req.url, req.param);

                console.log('=========================================================');
            }

            return next();
        },
```

req.allParams() returns it isn't a function and req.param(...) returns undefined. Do I have to impement this in another position? Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Bruno

**EDIT**

I use the default order inside the http.js :

```
order: [
            'startRequestTimer',
            'cookieParser',
            'session',
            'passportInit',
            'passportSession',
            'myRequestLogger',
            'bodyParser',
            'handleBodyParserError',
            'compress',
            'methodOverride',
            'poweredBy',
            '$custom',
            'router',
            'www',
            'favicon',
            '404',
            '500'
        ]
```

Comment: tried that aswell ... also undefined

Comment: It works for `GET` requests with route similar to `/:someparam`

Comment: but i want to log every request and its params

Comment: you can try `req.query` for route type `?someparam=`, `req.body` for post body (make sure to use route after `body-parser`)

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer ... The order has to be different. The requestLogger has to be implemented after the bodyParser:

```
order: [
            ...
            'bodyParser',
            'myRequestLogger',
            'handleBodyParserError',
            '...
        ]
```